# Silent as the grave

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Silent as the grave,
>   Paler than a ghost.
>   Trapped in cramped confines,
>   Yet still I'm seen by most.

What am I?

Simple riddle but hopefully not *too* easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> a mime?

Silent as the grave,

> mimes do not talk

Paler than a ghost.

> mimes wear white makeup

Trapped in cramped confines,

> mimes are known for pretending to be stuck in a glass box

Yet still I'm seen by most.

> most people have seen a mime

Comment: Nailed it! Not *exactly* what I had intended with the last clue but pretty much. It was more of a two part clue with being trapped in confines yet still being visible. The adjective you used to describe the confines explains how.

Answer (score 12):

Is it

> a tooth?

Silent as the grave

> a tooth is normally silent

Paler than a ghost

> a tooth is white

Trapped in cramped confines

> the mouth

Yet still I'm seen by most

> people can see your teeth when you smile

Comment: Very good answer (perhaps better than my intended?) but not the correct answer!

Answer (score 3):

> Window/glass

Silent as the grave,

> Glass cannot speak, right

Paler than a ghost.

> It's transparent (as you can or can not see)

Trapped in cramped confines,

> Thinking of window's frames (or any sort of display with glass)

Yet still I'm seen by most.

> Nearly everbody has a window around to look at/through

Comment: Not the answer but nice idea!

Answer (score 3):

> the eyes?, they are obviously silent, they are white, trapped in the eye cavities and it's one of the first things we see of another person

Answer (score 1):

It's

> Paper!

Silent as the grave,

> Obviously, paper is pretty quiet.

Paler than a ghost.

> Paper tends to be white.

Trapped in cramped confines,

> Paper in books have very little space between.

Yet still I'm seen by most.

> It's such a large part of everyday life, you probably see it many times a day.

Comment: Also a good answer and reasoning but not what I was looking for

Comment: I actually had the same reasoning I feel this would have been a possible answer